How to access Printer Ricoh IM-C300 webserver behind a router
I have several printers Ricoh IM-C300 on my local network. Some of them are behind a router.
I just want to access their webserver.
When I am physically behind their Router, I just type a printer IP on my browser and I get its local web page.
I want to do that but from outside this router.
Example :
This router has the IP 192.168.1.12.
This printer behind the router receives this IP 192.168.0.7.
On this router I forwarded 8080 to 80
But when I type on my browser 192.168.1.2:8080 the page is not found.
